# Set/Create Environment Variable using Java program that persist after execution prgram in linux

Tags: java, linux, unix

I need to create a java solution which can create/set the certain environment variable using Java Code. These new environment variable will be used by the another java program on the same machine. I found code which can create the environment variables in same process using processbuilder.

Comment: Hint: putting so many tags on your question is **not** a good thing to do. You have a java linux question; so, there is no need for a **windows** tag!

Answer (score 1):

That's not how environment variables work.

Environment variables are, in essence, an extra set of parameters that is passed into a program. If that program in turns launches a new program, then it can forward its environment variables, or not, and it can set (or unset) any other environment variables, or not, in that program it's launching; but environment variables are not a global property of a machine, and there's no way for a program to send an environment variable to another program just because they're on the same machine.

Instead, you'll need for your first program to store the necessary key-value mappings in a file somewhere on the host, and your second program to read those mappings.

That said, you may find it helpful to use environment variables as *part* of your solution; for example, you could have your first program write the key-value mappings in a format that Bash will interpret as setting environment variables:

```
export foo=bar
export baz=bip
```

and then launch your second program using a Bash *wrapper script* that first pulls in the key-value mappings (`source file_that_the_first_program_wrote_to.txt`) and then executes it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no persistence mechanism in Java for "environment variables".

This means that you have to look into **other** options means to persist information.

As you are talking about simple things that would fit into environment variables, the natural thing to use would be java [**Properties**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Meaning: you have one (or more) property files in defined places; and some of your Java programs just read those files; whereas others also might manipulate the content of those files.